# Sorting ListObject with Formulas Excel VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have data that I paste into a defined table.  In the table I have some calculations that I do on the data pasted in.  This calculations are included in the table object.

I created a button on the cover of my workbook to sort the table depending on what column they want.  Most of the sorting works correctly but it seems like the 'Variance' column is not.

Some issues that maybe be against the rules of excel but can't pin point the issue. I think it maybe a calc speed or calc order issue.

The 'Variance' formula in the Object table is a SUMIF formula that uses the criteria of a 'Customer' column that itself holds a CONCATENATE formula that references data pasted in.  Where it gets even more tricky is that the 'Variance' SUMIF formula is summing a column on the coversheet which itself has a SUMIF that is based on another cell that is finding the listed 'Customers.  I included a picture cause this is confusing and probably the worst way to do this? This wasn't part of the original design was just messing around with it.

I suspect it has something to do with the calculation order/speed as when I turn off Automatic Calculations the sorting works correctly.  Included below is my code and more detail.

[image]

Is there a way to make sure that the table calculates first

Thanks.

```
Sub SortCLINTable(sortType As String)

Dim modWS As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim modTable As ListObject




Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set modWS = wb.Worksheets("CustomerSheet")
Set modTable = modWS.ListObjects("CustomTable")


With modTable
.Sort.SortFields.CLEAR
.Sort.SortFields.Add _
    Key:=Range("CustomTable[" & sortType & "]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues,   Order:=xlAscending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal

 With .Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
 End With

End With


End Sub
```

Comment: You could simply do `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` at the beginning of your procedure, and then re-set to `= xlCalculationAutomatic` before the `End Sub` statement. I know that doesn't identify the root cause, but if manual calculation solves the problem, something to consider...

Comment: Thanks that is a work around for sure.  That seems to have fix most of the issue.  Just have to make sure that if it errors it goes back and turns on the Automatic calc.  Do you think it is crazy to have a macro do this sorting function?